# How to bulk insert with a select subquery

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm using Sequelize in my project but I'm facing some trouble to translate in simple query into Sequelize. In addition, I'm looking for a way to bulk insert this query.

The query:

```sql
INSERT INTO productstatistics (shopId, productId, average, min, max) 
VALUES (SELECT p."shopId", p."productId", avg(p."basicPrice") as average, min(p."basicPrice"), max(p."basicPrice") FROM productprice p 
WHERE p."productId" = 123 AND p."shopId" = 321)
```

For the context, I have 3 tables: Shops, Products and productPrices.
Each products is present in each shop. And each combinaison product / shop, productPrices have a historic of all the prices in that shop.

Here, I'm trying to create a new table productstatistics with some statistics from those 3 tables.

The first thing I tried is to loop over all my shops, then over all my products and do the [Sequelize raw query](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/raw-queries/).

But in my case, this is more than 3 000 000 records. I can do that in async but It takes forever, or doing in with `Promise.all()` but then I reach a :

> JavaScript heap out of memory

How to use Sequelize in the best way to achieve my goal? Is there a way to use Sequelize to run the query describe earlier with all my products and all my shops?

Comment: Can you post some of the sequelize code you are using? It's impossible to understand why you would get JavaScript heap errors from just the SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need to use `Sequelize.query` to execute this raw SQL query you indicated in the question OR execute `SELECT` part of the query as a raw SQL query (again using `Sequelize.query`) from `productprice` by chunks using `limit` and `offset` options and use `bulkInsert` of the Sequelize model.